# How to pass a conditional statement if n number of strings contain particular input charactrs and store only matching strings list array in new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, logic

I'm unable to solve a problem: I want to check if 'names' string of an array includes searchInput characters. If I find any matching characters, then store all names string's parent objects of an array in a new array.

my new array sometimes abnormally shows empty even if there is a match. Please check if I did anything wrong with the logic or some other problem.

```
const search = document.querySelector('#search');
const ul = document.querySelector('.student-list');

function nameSearch(list){ 
   let newList = []; 
   const searchInput = search.value.toLowerCase();
   for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
      let names = `${list[i].name.first.toLowerCase()} ${list[i].name.last.toLowerCase()}`;
      if(searchInput.length != 0 && names.includes(searchInput)){
         newList.push(list[i]);    
      }
```

Comment: "even if there is a chance for a match" ... because ... ?

Comment: I meant even if there is a match. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Why do you think that there is a match? Please provide a concrete [mre] that shows where your code does not work.

Comment: The newList array shows empty even if there is a match which supposed to store the matched names parent array list